# Sorting array for export into .csv file - PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to format my array properly for exportation into a `.csv` file am having an issue sorting properly.  A user will upload an existing `.csv` file and this will take the data and use accordingly.  I am trying to format it so names within an index are alphabetical.

Here is what I am getting when I have this printed into a csv file using the following:

```
foreach($collectedData as $row) {
    if( !isset($normalized[$row[6]]) ) {
        $normalized[$row[6]] = array();
    }
    $normalized[$row[6]][] = $row;
}
print_r($normalized);
```

Results:

```
Array   
(   
    [Leonardo] => Array 
        (   
            [0] => Array    
                (   
                    [0] => 2    
                    [1] => 230  
                    [2] => 12 Aug 2013 07:46 AM 
                    [3] => 81680852 
                    [4] => INB  
                    [5] => 1.38 
                    [6] => Leonardo 
                )   

            [1] => Array    
                (   
                    [0] => 11   
                    [1] => 230  
                    [2] => 12 Aug 2013 08:35 AM 
                    [3] => 80411600 
                    [4] => INB  
                    [5] => 8.23 
                    [6] => Leonardo 
                )   

            [2] => Array    
                (   
                    [0] => 15   
                    [1] => 230  
                    [2] => 12 Aug 2013 09:03 AM 
                    [3] => 5122382  
                    [4] => INB  
                    [5] => 3.92 
                    [6] => Leonardo 
                )   

            [3] => Array    
                (   
                    [0] => 16   
                    [1] => 230  
                    [2] => 12 Aug 2013 09:09 AM 
                    [3] => 51275678 
                    [4] => INB  
                    [5] => 0.38 
                    [6] => Leonardo 
                )   

            [4] => Array    
                (   
                    [0] => 20   
                    [1] => 230  
                    [2] => 12 Aug 2013 10:06 AM 
                    [3] => 7367755  
                    [4] => INB  
                    [5] => 1.05 
                    [6] => Leonardo 
                )   

            [5] => Array    
                (   
                    [0] => 25   
                    [1] => 230  
                    [2] => 12 Aug 2013 10:22 AM 
                    [3] => 5831200  
                    [4] => INB  
                    [5] => 0.35 
                    [6] => Leonardo 
                )   

            [6] => Array    
                (   
                    [0] => 30   
                    [1] => 230  
                    [2] => 12 Aug 2013 11:25 AM 
                    [3] => 3333636  
                    [4] => INB  
                    [5] => 1.63 
                    [6] => Leonardo 
                )   

...........
```

This is what I want because it is formatted with the names clumped together.  But when imploding it into a `.csv` file it does not work.

The following results are using same method but with imploding statements:

```
foreach($collectedData as $row) {
    if( !isset($normalized[$row[6]]) ) {
        $normalized[$row[6]] = array();

         echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
    }
    $normalized[$row[6]][] = $row;
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
}
```

Results:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6
2   230 8/12/2013 7:46  8168670852  INB 1.38    Leonardo
11  230 8/12/2013 8:35  8045411600  INB 8.23    Leonardo
0   1   2   3   4   5   6
12  200 8/12/2013 8:44  8162155081  INB 0.52    Rick
15  230 8/12/2013 9:03  5176722382  INB 3.92    Leonardo
16  230 8/12/2013 9:09  5123175678  INB 0.38    Leonardo
...and so on
```

Notice how Rick is in with the Leonardo names?  My question is how do I format it correctly so that the `print_r($normalized)` results are the same as when I implode them into the `.csv` file?

Comment: use fputcsv in php to populate your csv

Comment: Ya it is not what I need.